# Как подружить Vue Js и Flask Form? Передача параметров с '-'

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, jinja2

Есть форма:

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Форма через представление передается в шаблонизатор jinja2:

```
...
form = UserForm()
return render_template('/tmp.html', form=form)
```

Поле для ввода рендериться так:

```
{{ form.name }}
```

И, если нужно, так:

```
{{ form.name(class="form-control", placeholder="Имя") }}
```

Но! Так - нельзя. Почему? Как подружить Vue и Flask Form?

```
{{ form.name(class="form-control", placeholder="Имя", v-model="user.name") }}

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
{{ form.name(class="form-control", placeholder="Имя", **{'v-model':'user.name'}) }}
```